# For which positive, real $a$ do the series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For which real $a \gt 0$ do the series converge?

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(\sqrt[n^2]{n^2}-1\right)^a$$

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, but with no success, hence why I posted this here. This was a question on my exam.

Comment: What did you try with no success? Which similar series can you attack with success? Which series do you know are convergent? What do you know about $\sqrt[n^2]{n^2}$ when $n$ is large? And so on.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n^2]{n^2} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} {n^2}^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\ln \left( {n^2}^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \right)}\\
&= e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}  \ln \left( {n^2}^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \right)}\\
&= e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}  \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \ln (n^2) \right)}\\
&= e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}  \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \ln (n^2) \right)}\\
&= e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}  \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot 2\ln n \right)}\\
&= e^{\lim_{x \to 0}  \left(x^2 \cdot 2\ln \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right)}\\
&= e^{-2 \lim_{x \to 0}  \left(x^2 \ln x \right)}\\
&= e^{-2 \lim_{x \to 0}  \left(\frac{\ln x}{x^2} \right)}\\
&= e^{-2 \lim_{x \to 0}  \left(\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-2}{x^3}} \right)}\\
&= e^{\frac{-2}{-2} \lim_{x \to 0}  \left(\frac{x^3}{x} \right)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} e^{x^2}\\
&= 1 + x^2 + O(x^2)
\end{align}$$
you can see that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n^2]{n^2}-1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right) - 1 \right) = \frac{1}{n^2} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)$$
and thus
$$n \to \infty \Rightarrow \sqrt[n^2]{n^2}-1 \approx \frac{1}{n^2} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)$$
so
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\sqrt[n^2]{n^2}-1)^a \text{converges} \iff \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^a \text{converges} \iff \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2a}} \text{converges}$$
and the last serie is much easier to examine.
In fact you get that
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\sqrt[n^2]{n^2}-1)^a \text{converges} \iff \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2a}} \text{converges} \iff 2a > 1 \iff a > \frac{1}{2}$$